# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.length') in Safari

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, safari, amcharts

I am using AmCharts to display a graph on my site.

it worked in Safari on Aug 29th. Havn't changed anything except some text underneath the graph since then. (checked my git history).

But somehow, when I checked it today, the graph was broken.

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b[0].time')

from Serial.js line 24-25

Serial.js is a linechart library from AmCharts I am using. I havn't updated it or changed anything in it either.

I have no idea why I started getting this error. It seems to be related to the data given to the chart component.

when I comment out the AmCharts react component, it works fine.

Along with the error an AJAX call is made, which fetches chart data from an API also fails, somehow running the same Serial.js code.

I tried forcing it to not put the chart on the page until all of the data has been retrieved.

```
if (chartData[0]) {
      if (chartData[0].market) {
        console.log(chartData);
        chart = (
          <div id="result-chart" className={this.state.chartClass}>
            {React.createElement(AmCharts.React, config)}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

The error occours when the following AJAX call is running:

```
getAnnualData() {
    $.ajax(`https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC.json?trim_start=1970-01-01&collapse=monthly&column=4&auth_token=XXXXX`)
    .then((r) => {
      let fixedData = r.data.map((point) => {
        return point[1].toFixed(0)
      })
      fixedData = fixedData.reverse()

      let percent = null;
      for(var e = 0; e < fixedData.length; e++) {
                if(e < 1) {
                    percent = (25000 * 100) / fixedData[0] / 100;
                }
                fixedData[e] = Math.floor(percent * fixedData[e]);
            }

      this.set('annualData', fixedData)
    })
    .fail((e) => {
      console.error('Failed fetching QUANDL DATA', e)
    })
  },
```

the fail 'Failed fetching QUANDL DATA' is running. The error passed a long here is the same as first mentioned.

Looking at the stack trace the error occours at the following event:

```
onDataUpdated — serial.js:25:412
```

For that code to even run, I'd assume that the data must be there. Otherwise it should never run any AmCharts code.

The weirdest thing however, is that this only happens on Safari... It works fine on Chrome, Edge & Firefox...

Debugging this has also proven extremely difficult, as none of my console logs shows up on this page on Safari.

However it is definitely connected to the Ajax call somehow. I have other AmCharts graphs on another page. ALl the ones that use data from that AJAX call is broken in Safari. However the linecharts not using that dataset works fine... (all of them works fine in other browsers however)

I also checked the actual data I am getting back and using from Quandl. and the data looks fine.

I tried manually setting the market keys on the chartData to nothing. And the code to put the graph on the page never runs and there's no errors. I then also tried setting it to a fixed number. Everytime. The code ran and I still got the error. So it's definitely not due to "bad" API data.

I am using Babel to compile the ES6 code.

Here's the code used to generate the chartData:

```
let basicData = store.plans.get('basic').get('annualData')
    let premiumData = store.plans.get('premium').get('annualData')
    let businessData = store.plans.get('business').get('annualData')
    // let fundData = store.plans.get('fund').get('annualData')


    let marketData = store.market.data.get('annualData')

    let fixedData = basicData.map((point, i) => {

      let premiumBalance = 0
      let businessBalance = 0
      // let fundBalance = 0
      let marketBalance = 0

      if (premiumData[i]) { premiumBalance = premiumData[i].balance }
      if (businessData[i]) { businessBalance = businessData[i].balance }
      // if (fundData[i]) { fundBalance = fundData[i].balance }
      if (marketData[i]) { marketBalance = marketData[i] }

      return {
        basic: point.balance,
        premium: premiumBalance,
        business: businessBalance,
        // fund: fundBalance,
        market: marketBalance,

        basicBalloon: formatPrice(point.balance),
        premiumBalloon: formatPrice(premiumBalance),
        businessBalloon: formatPrice(businessBalance),
        // fundBalloon: formatPrice(fundBalance),
        marketBalloon: formatPrice(marketBalance),

        date: `${point.date.year}-${point.date.month}-${point.date.day}`
      }
    })

    function formatPrice(value) {
        while(/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(value.toString())) {
            value = value.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
        }
        let price = '$' + value;
        return price;
    }

    let chartData = []
    if (this.state.animate && this.state.fetched) {
      chartData = fixedData;
    }
```

In case it is relevant here's the config for the chart:

```
let config = {
  type: "serial",
  theme: "dark",
  addClassNames: true,


  dataProvider: chartData,

  balloon: {
    color: '#49494A',
    fillAlpha: 1,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderThickness: 0,
  },

  graphs: [
    {
      id: "market",
      lineColor: "#49494A",

      bullet: "square",
      bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
      bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
      bulletSize: 5,
      hideBulletsCount: 10,
      lineThickness: 2,
      useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
      valueField: "market",
      "balloonText": "<div class=\"chart-balloon\"><span class=\"plan-name market-name\">S&P 500</span><span class=\"balloon-value\">[[marketBalloon]]</span></div>",
    },
    {
    id: "basic",
    lineColor: "#FFFFFF",

    bullet: "square",
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
    bulletSize: 5,
    hideBulletsCount: 10,
    lineThickness: 2,
    useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
    valueField: "basic",
    balloonText: "<div class=\"chart-balloon\"><span class=\"plan-name\">Basic</span><span class=\"balloon-value\">[[basicBalloon]]</span></div>"
  },
  {
    id: "premium",
    lineColor: "#FFFFFF",

    bullet: "square",
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
    bulletSize: 5,
    hideBulletsCount: 10,
    lineThickness: 2,
    useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
    valueField: "premium",
    balloonText: "<div class=\"chart-balloon\"><span class=\"plan-name\">Premium</span><span class=\"balloon-value\">[[premiumBalloon]]</span></div>"
  },
  {
    id: "business",
    lineColor: "#FFFFFF",

    bullet: "square",
    bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
    bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
    bulletSize: 5,
    hideBulletsCount: 10,
    lineThickness: 2,
    useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
    valueField: "business",
    "balloonText": "<div class=\"chart-balloon\"><span class=\"plan-name\">Business</span><span class=\"balloon-value\">[[businessBalloon]]</span></div>",
  }
],
  valueAxes: [{
    logarithmic: true,
    unit: '$',
    unitPosition: 'left',
    gridAlpha: 0.15,
    minorGridEnabled: true,
    dashLength: 0,
    inside: true,
        }],

  chartCursor: {
        valueLineEnabled: true,
        valueLineAlpha: 0.5,
        fullWidth: true,
        cursorAlpha: 0.5
    },

  categoryField: "date",
  categoryAxis: {
    parseDates: true,
    equalSpacing: true,
  },

};

if (store.session.browserType() === 'Safari') {
  config.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-M-D",
  config.categoryAxis = {
    equalSpacing: true,
  }
}
```

And yes, I have tried taking out the Safari specific code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Github history for the file with the graph component: https://github.com/MarkLyck/Formula-Stocks/commits/master/app/scripts/components/home/TheResults.js

Comment: Didn't read the full question as i'm going to bed, but I see you're using `let`: http://caniuse.com/#search=let It's only supported from iOS10 which is only out for like a month.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I am using Babel to compile that. That is definietly not the cause.